# Heroku follower delay

Tags: heroku

I want to create followers for my database. Now I wonder if there is a significant delay between the master and the follower state.

Can I write to a master and read immediately after from a follower instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a variable delay, that depends on network latency between master/slave, volume of data being replicated, and locks/transactions that may effect replicated data on the slave.

Due to all of these things, you should consider the slave to be a valid point in time snapshot of the database, but not a current one.

There is a synchronous replication mode available in Postgres, but not on Heroku Postgres.  This synchronous mode waits for a write to be written to the slaves before acknowledging it written on the master.  This can be a dangerous feature, introducing high latency or bigger problems if the master/slave are partitioned.  I don't recommend it.

If you need guaranteed reads of current data, you should be reading from the master.

Anecdotally, our slave is at most 100-200 commits behind the master, when we run blocking reporting jobs on the slave.